# Pointing to a relative location of a XML file without embedding it in the SWF

Tags: xml, apache-flex

My Flex application uses an XML configuration file for most of its text content. The text will change over time, so I'd like to be able to edit it without rebuilding the application.

Originally, I used the syntax

```
<fx:Model id="xmlFile" source="projects.xml"/>
```

but this embeds the xml file into the SWF file. This syntax

```
<fx:Model id="xmlFile" source="http://mywebpage.com/projects.xml"/>
```

will work, but when the URL changes (for example, moving from a development server to production server), I would have to change the URL and rebuild the application.

This file will always be in the same location, relative to the application's SWF file (http://mywebpage.com/myapp.swf).  Is there any way to use a relative location in the source property without using a specific URL, giving me a XML file that isn't embedded into the SWF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to load it at runtime using [HTTPService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html) or [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html)--for a web app--or the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class for an AIR or Mobile app.

If you are willing to assume that your XML file will always be loaded from the same server as the SWF, you can use relative links to load it instead of absolute links.

For an app I built for a client, we used an external XML file to hold the details of the server containing our services.  Of course, that config file is in a specific location on the same server that is serving the SWF.